# "Build number" в андроид Java

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как в андроид Java получить версию прошивки "Build number", которая отображается в "О телефоне". Нигде не могу найти...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697008/how-to-get-device-aosp-build-number-in-android-devices-programmatically

Comment: Спасибо!
Точный метод: Build.DISPLAY